# Broadcom STA [4727] Wireless not detecting after driver installation

Tags: 12.04, broadcom

I have a Broadcom 802.11n [4727] wifi adapter..
I searched a LOT and found out we need to do some steps in order to get the wifi working.

So for this i have no idea how much of installations and blacklisting i have done and still in the end my wireless is still not detected.
("wireless" option does not appear under "Network")

I could really use some help to get my wifi working soon. ty!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless card (the same as you) and I had the very same problem: my WPA router network was not showing up.

You just have to change the wireless channel on your router and that's it!
Try one under 12. For instance, I found that channel 3 and 4 worked great for me.

Hope that works.